# How to access properties of a context class (non-static) inside a Nest.js interceptor

Tags: nestjs, decorator, interceptor

I am trying to create an interceptor for audit logging. Here I want to get previous data if the request is PUT or PATCH, so I want to access different services in my app to get the document before processing.

The problem is that I am trying to access the context class in the interceptor to get the service associated with the context class, but it is not possible to access the service. I could access the static variable, is there anyway to access non-static members such as service inside the interceptor by using `getContext()`?

```js
@Injectable()
export class AuditLoggingInterceptor implements NestInterceptor {
  private readonly logger = new Logger(AuditLoggingInterceptor.name);
  constructor(
    private readonly auditlogService: AuditLogService,
    private readonly reflector: Reflector,
    private readonly moduleRef: ModuleRef,
  ) {}

  async intercept(
    context: ExecutionContext,
    next: CallHandler,
  ): Promise<Observable<any>> {
    const req = context?.switchToHttp()?.getRequest();
    const res = context?.switchToHttp()?.getResponse();
    const ctx: any = context.getClass();
    console.log(ctx, ctx.prototype, ctx.test, 'testing');
    console.log(ctx.chec );
   // how to access service inside class?
   
return next.handle().pipe(
      tap(async (data) => {
     
        return data;
      }),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my knowledge, if the service is `private` in the controller, you won't be able to access it directly (if it's public you could use `ModuleRef.get(controller).service`), but you can use some clever tricks and reflection to get what you're looking for. I was able to contrive a non-type safe example that should probably be hacked upon to be more stable, but the idea is to get the `design:paramtypes` metadata from the controller, which should be the injected providers, and then find the class that has the same prefix as the current controller with the `Service` postfix to it, and then use `ModuleRef` to grab it from the DI container.

```js
import {
  CallHandler,
  ExecutionContext,
  Injectable,
  NestInterceptor,
} from '@nestjs/common';
import { ModuleRef, Reflector } from '@nestjs/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class AppInterceptor implements NestInterceptor {
  constructor(
    private readonly moduleRef: ModuleRef,
    private readonly reflector: Reflector,
  ) {}

  intercept(context: ExecutionContext, next: CallHandler): Observable<any> {
    const featureName = context.getClass().name.replace('Controller', '');
    const controllerDeps = Reflect.getMetadata(
      'design:paramtypes',
      context.getClass(),
    );
    const serviceRef = controllerDeps.find((dep) => {
      return dep.name?.match(featureName + 'Service');
    });
    const service = this.moduleRef.get(serviceRef, { strict: false });
    console.log(service.getHello());
    return next.handle();
  }
}
```

I did this with a simple `nest new` project and the `AppController` and `AppService`, but the idea should extend out to anything you need it to. Please make sure to add type safety to this and use it only where necessary.